# In the requests package, how to pass several values for one key in the payload params?

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler

I am trying to get a list of merchandise category ID, so that I can put them into urls and scrape the products information. I know how to put single values to keys like:

```
payload = {'catID': 'ID_V2L0_65'}
```

But I'm confused when I have many catIDs. Here's some of my code:

```
navi_info = requests.get('https://shopee.co.id/api/v4/recommend/recommend?bundle=top_sold_product_microsite&limit=20&offset=0')
catIDs = [catID for catID in navi_info.json['data']['sections']['index']['key']]
payload = {'catID': catIDs[0]}
r = requests.get('https://shopee.co.id/top_products', params=payload)
```

Comment: website: https://shopee.co.id/top_products; data: https://shopee.co.id/api/v4/recommend/recommend?bundle=top_sold_product_microsite&limit=20&offset=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "index" key is nested inside of an array within the JSON message (the value of "sections" is an array).

A solution to this problem could be:

```
navi_info = requests.get('https://shopee.co.id/api/v4/recommend/recommend?bundle=top_sold_product_microsite&limit=20&offset=0')
print(navi_info.json()['data']['sections'])
# extracts all the "index" data from all "sections"
index_arrays = [object_['index'] for object_ in navi_info.json()['data']['sections']]
index_array = index_arrays[0] # only one section with "index" key is present
# extract all catIDs from the "index" payload
catIDs = [object_['key'] for object_ in index_array]
payload = {'catID': catIDs}
print(payload)
```

The payload should then look like `{'catID': ['ID_V2L0_65', 'ID_V2L0_3693', 'ID_V2L0_2', 'ID_V2L0_19', 'ID_V2L0_75', 'ID_V2L0_4040',...]}`